What does "Information above is provided for referencial use." mean?
I'm looking at some "e-ticket itinerary/receipt" issued by Korean Air for a flight from the United States to Asia. I read the baggage information section and it says:

Information above is provided for referencial use.

Does that mean that whatever information it contains, it might be incorrect and I would have to pay the price for any incorrectness? (Eg, if it says that the maximum weight is 23 kg but in fact it's 20 kg then I'll have to pay some extra fee)

Ticket:


"Above" refers to "further up on the page", so the dimensions and weights of various luggage types listed there.
"Referential use" generally means that the information was correct as the last time they checked, but it is not the authoritative text, which might be different and have exceptions or special requirements not listed in the referential material.

And, FWIW, "referencial use" isn't a very idiomatic translation of the Korean into English, which is part of the problem.

Trish, I see your edit, my point was I don't think the word "above" was unclear to the OP.   "Referencial", as ohwilleke pointed out, isn't a common word, and that's what they asked about.  (note what the green arrow points to)  I'm actually not totally convinced it is even a proper word in the English language...

They were close. The common phrasing would be "Information above is provided for reference only."
